# Nginx geo variable not working in if clause

Tags: nginx

Using Nginx 1.4.6, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have this in the http section of `nginx.conf`:

```
geo $maintenance {
    default         1;
    86.161.27.175   0;
}
```

In my site config I have this:

```
error_page 503 /static/errors/503.html;
location /mydir/ {
    if ($maintenance) {
        return 503;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

However, I am always getting a 503 error when viewing `/mydir/` on my site, but for my IP that shouldn't be happening. I've double checked and that is definitely my current IP. I have another geo section for rate limiting that is working fine. Manually setting `$maintenance` to 0 just above the location block works fine.

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem: I had CloudFlare turned on for my staging site, so it was receiving a CloudFlare IP, not my actual IP. D'oh!

Comment: you should `include /etc/nginx/cloudflare ;` on your server block to get real IP, and create that file cloudflare with somthing like this  `set_real_ip_from 204.93.240.0/24; `