# How do I set up a toggle for an Apache RewriteRule?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, 503-error

I have the following Apache config, which displays a 503 Service Unavailable error to all visitors except for my IP address:

```
ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127.0.0.1$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/503.html$
RewriteRule .* - [R=503]
```

This is so that I can carry out maintenance on my site without errors showing for users. (I'm using my actual IP, not `127.0.0.1`.)

However, to turn this off or on I need to comment/uncomment all the lines, or completely remove it. On my other server running nginx I used a geo clause with a variable (as seen [in this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/765891/nginx-geo-variable-not-working-in-if-clause)). So I can just change `default` from `0` to `1` to turn it on.

Is there a way to do something similar in Apache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to restart Apache to change settings (which is a requirement for changes in the configuration) and you're not using `.htaccess` files (which you don't want to, [really](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when))

You could set up what we do (via our loadbalancer usually though), a test for a maintenance status e.g. by adding a test

```
RewriteCond ^/maintenance.txt -f
```

where a maintenance window starts by  creating a maintenance.txt file (e.g. with `touch maintenance.txt`) on the otherwise live site.

Answer (score 0):

Look into how Debian/Ubuntu configure Apache. They use configuration excerpts for sites, modules and general configuration stored in files in `/etc/apache2/{mod|sites|conf}-available` that gets symlinked into `/etc/apache2/{mod|sites|conf}-enabled` to activate it. These `*-enabled` directories are `Include`ed in the main config file. Additional, they have `a2Xen` and `a2Xdis` commands that just create the symlink or delete it for easy maintenance.

Comment: I don't want to disable a site completely, I want to serve a 503 to everyone except me temporarily.

Comment: This is a way to quickly add and remove configuration parts. You put your config fragment into a file and you can activate or deactivate this fragment quickly by creating or removing a single symlink. However, for this specific problem,  I like HBruijns method better anyway.

Answer (score 0):

HBruijn's answer is the best but here's another option I just discovered that works:

```
RewriteCond 1 0
```

Then the `0` can be changed to `1` to toggle it on.